# How do I find similar duplicates from excel columns?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

My excel spreadsheet has the following datasets, but as can you see some are duplicates, while others have similar names. I want to find duplicates that are same and similar. The condition is that if they have three or more than three similar keywords, then they are also duplicate. I have the following excel function, but how do I expand it to find similar duplicates:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($C$2:C2,C2)>1, "Duplicate!","Original")
```

Spreadsheet:

```
The Power by Naomi Alderman
Grant by Ron Chernow*********
Exit West by Mohsin Hamid
Janesville: An American Story by Amy Goldstein
Exit West by Mohsin Hamid
Five-Carat Soul by James McBride
Anything Is Possible by Elizabeth Strout
Dying: A Memoir by Cory Taylor
A Gentleman in Moscow by Amor Towles
Janesville: An American Story by Amy Goldstein
Exit West by Mohsin Hamid
Five-Carat Soul by James McBride
Janesville: An  Story by Amy 
Exit West by Mohsin Hamid
Five-Carat Soul by James McBride
Evicted: Poverty and Profit in the American City Matthew Desmond
Exit West by Mohsin Hamid
An American Story by Amy Goldstein
Poverty and Profit American City Matthew 
Grant by Ron*********
Grant by Ron Chernow
```

As you can see ***Grant by Ron Chernow*** has multiple exact same duplicates and there is another one that simply has ***Grant by Ron*** without ***Chernow***. Please help.

Here is the screenshot: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YL0SL.jpg)

Comment: What not clear to me is if the content of a given line is in a single cell or multiple cells. For example, is "The Power by Naomi Alderman" a single cell or five? or a different number?

Comment: Please see the screenshot. https://imgur.com/a/F0t2r

Answer (score 0):

If the sequence of your data cannot be altered, I can't think of a way to do what you need, using just Excel functions (but considering the brilliant minds in this site, I can't be so sure). If however you can sort the data, then below formula might work.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(C$2:C2,C2 & "*")>1,"Duplicate!","Original")
```

But after sorting your data in *descending order*.

**Considerations:**

1. Data should be sorted descending order
2. The duplicates being tracked have the same starting word or phrase.

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to sort this should work. You can change the number 11 to identify the number of characters from the left you want to match.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(C$2:C2, LEFT(C2,11)& "*")>1, "Duplicate!","Original")
```